Boton de agregar con formset django
Hola estoy empezando a utilizar django 5 y estoy haciendo un proyecto web para sortear el amigo invisible
Mi problema es que a la hora de utilizar formset no son dinámicos por lo que no puedo crear un número de formularios a petición del usuario
tengo este formulario
class ParticipanteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participante
        fields = ['nombre', 'email']
        
ParticipanteFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteForm)

Este modelo:
class Participante(models.Model):
    sorteo = models.ForeignKey(Sorteo, related_name='participantes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

y esta vista donde renderizo los formulario y guardo los datos:
def crear_sorteo(request):
    sorteo_form = SorteoForm(request.POST or None)
    ParticipanteFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteForm, extra=3)
    participante_formset = ParticipanteFormSet(request.POST or None)
    
    context = {
        'sorteo_form': sorteo_form,
        'participante_formset': participante_formset,
    }
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if sorteo_form.is_valid():
            sorteo = sorteo_form.save()  # Guarda el sorteo primero
            if participante_formset.is_valid():
                for participante_form in participante_formset:
                    participante = participante_form.save(commit=False)
                    participante.sorteo = sorteo  # Asigna el sorteo al participante
                    participante.save()
                return render(request, 'sorteo_realizado.html')
    
    return render(request, 'crear_sorteo.html', context) 

Como se ve ParticipanteFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteForm, extra=3) segun el numero de extra que indiques sera el numero de formularios que se van a crear pero me gustaria que en la template:
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ sorteo_form }}
        {{ participante_formset.management_data }} 
        {{ participante_formset.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Realizar sorteo">
    </form>
</body>

haya un botón para agregar un participante y así el usuario meta todos los usuarios que quiera con un mínimo de 3 participantes,
He probado a hacer un botón que realiza un post y al recibirlo el número de extra se actualiza +1, pero la página se recarga y se pierden los datos, si alguien sabe como se puede hacer sería de mucha ayuda, gracias de antemano

Finalmente consegui resolverlo:
En la template hay que añadir la siguiente variable django {{ participante_formset.management_form }}la cual nos permite trabajar con formularios, ademas de añadir un botón para agregar participantes que va a llamar a una función de js que se va a encargar de añadir formularios con distintos ids para que no se queden con el mismo nombre, finalmente la template quedaria asi:
<body>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ sorteo_form }}
        {{ participante_formset.management_form }}
        <div id='participante-form-list'>
            {% for form in participante_formset %}
            <div class='participante-form'>
                {{ participante_formset.as_p }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div id='empty-form' class='hidden'>{{ participante_formset.empty_form.as_p }}</div>
        <button id='add-more' type='button'>+ participante</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Realizar sorteo">
    </form>
</body>

Junto con el js:
<script>
    const addMoreBtn = document.getElementById('add-more')
    const totalNewForms = document.getElementById('id_participante-TOTAL_FORMS')
    addMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', add_new_form)

    function add_new_form(event) {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault()
        }

        const currentParticipantes = document.getElementsByClassName('participante-form')
        let currentFormCount = currentParticipantes.length

        const formCopyTarget = document.getElementById('participante-form-list')
        const copyEmptyFormEL = document.getElementById('empty-form').cloneNode(true)
        copyEmptyFormEL.setAttribute('class', 'participante-form')
        copyEmptyFormEL.setAttribute('id', `form-${currentFormCount}`)
        const regex = new RegExp('__prefix__', 'g')
        copyEmptyFormEL.innerHTML = copyEmptyFormEL.innerHTML.replace(regex,
        currentFormCount)
        totalNewForms.setAttribute('value', currentFormCount + 1)

        formCopyTarget.append(copyEmptyFormEL)
    }
</script>

Por ultimo en la view solo hay que declarar el formset con extra a 0 ParticipanteFormSet = formset_factory(ParticipanteForm, extra=0)
Llegue a este codigo gracias al siguiente video que seguramente les sirva mucho igual que a mi
https://youtu.be/s3T-w2jhDHE?si=VD-3srsjElduxw5_
